# Problems using JQuery resources 1.10.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-drive-api

I am using google drive to host the following website:
https://e8edf64c16f714a3eb501e781f477ae636ff655a.googledrive.com/host/0B-CU-bHZqNGdeWd1RTlZd0xGUFU

I have the following code in my index.html file:

```
<!-- These are my resources -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"/>
<script src="resources/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="resources/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script src="resources/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
```

But i am getting this console error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I am not sure what is going on here, this use to work just fine.

Comment: Installed any extensions recently? Have you tried disabling any extensions you do have?

Comment: @j08691 no extensions running. I have attempted to run this on multiple browsers also, still no luck.

Comment: And the paths are all working? You checked the console?

Comment: console gives back this error: GET https://28af8f9cb43833f25c5d59aaa78580c73e8dbcd5-e8edf64c16f714a3eb501e781f…urces/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED